# Error logging in: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, create-react-app, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Error logging in: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined] i am integrate my app into aws amplify.But,I got above error.How i solve this error and i check my dynamodb table.No tables are created.